# Linker failed while linking custom .so library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, build.gradle

Something happened with my `Android Studio` or my `gradle-wrapper` or something when I clicked update and the project does not build anymore.

This is my error log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:myLibArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary'.
A build operation failed.
Linker failed while linking myLib.so.
See the complete log at: file:///mypath/app/build/tmp/myLibArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary/output.txt
```

The output.txt says:

```
android-ndk/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-
x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-
linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_java3 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also here is my gradle code:

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId "my.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName = "MyApp"
            cppFlags.add("-I${file(getOpenCVDir())}/sdk/native/jni/include".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-frtti")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            ldLibs.addAll(["log", "opencv_java3"])
            stl = "gnustl_static"
        }

        abis {
            create("arm64-v8a") {
                ldFlags.add("-L${file(getOpenCVDir())}/sdk/native/libs/arm64-v8a".toString())
            }
            create("armeabi") {
                ldFlags.add("-L${file(getOpenCVDir())}/sdk/native/libs/armeabi".toString())
            }
            create("armeabi-v7a") {
                ldFlags.add("-L${file(getOpenCVDir())}/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a".toString())
            }
            create("mips") {
                ldFlags.add("-L${file(getOpenCVDir())}/sdk/native/libs/mips".toString())
            }
            create("mips64") {
                ldFlags.add("-L${file(getOpenCVDir())}/sdk/native/libs/mips64".toString())
            }
            create("x86") {
                ldFlags.add("-L${file(getOpenCVDir())}/sdk/native/libs/x86".toString())
            }
            create("x86_64") {
                ldFlags.add("-L${file(getOpenCVDir())}/sdk/native/libs/x86_64".toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm on `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'` and I use `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`
libopencv_java3.so is in every folder specified in the `abis {}`

Things I've already tried:

- completely uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio
- File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart
- ./gradlew clean and Build -> Clean Project
- change ndk version (I've used r12 and r13)
- change gradle version back to 2.10 and experimental to 0.7.0 how it was before
- revert project to previous commit
- pull and create source into a different project

One other thing to note, the same exact code works on my college's computer with the same Gradle and Android Studio version (2.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem which was actually really stupid but I will let anyone who experiences this know. My openCV SDK folder was somehow synced to my iCloud storage and all of a sudden, Android Studio could not access the files there anymore and the gradle could not build the libraries for me.
I have moved the SDK folder to a non-syncing folder and everything started working again.